# Restrict access of web site/API to only the local internet/WiFi without setting it up locally

Tags: wordpress, security

I have an ongoing project for a dental clinic which requires patients who comes to the clinic to register using a WordPress site as the frontend and a rest API to process the registration that i have made. After some thought, I wouldn't want people to use the API or the site outside of the clinic since this app will only be used when people come to the clinic itself. I did some research and from what I understand, I would need to host it locally and to not port forward it. Using this approach is a bit of a hassle for me since all the "security" part and the maintenance and setup would need to be done me which I currently not have a lot of knowledge on. I plan to probably host the API using AWS or some other cloud providers and have it interact with the WordPress site only but I'm not sure how to prevent people to access the WordPress and API outside of the clinic. Any idea on how I can solve this or maybe any way that I could host the application using a cloud provider and have it only be accessed via the clinic's WiFi/internet?

PS: I'm not sure what tag I should be using for this kind of problem but I added some tags which i think would be relevant to this. If it should be change or need more tags, please advise.

Comment: "host using AWS" and "restrict access to only the local internet/wifi" is mutually exclusive if you don't plan to move the clinic to one of their datacenters

Comment: @NicoHaase , I guess that is unachievable. Is there any approach i can use to prevent people outside the clinic to not access it because I'm concerned with the security part since its dealing with sensitive data or is setting up the API locally within the clinic itself is the only way to solve this?

Comment: You can use any mechanism for a IP based restriction if the clinic has a static IP address, or place the server inside of their network

Comment: why would login system not work?

Comment: @silver, I am considering that option but imo it does feel a bit of a hassle as a patient in need of signing up just to fill out the form.

Comment: just to be clear, you want patient to FILL UP THE FORM using their own device with their own network data? but only allow them to access the site when they're inside clinic?

Comment: @silver, i would like the patient to fill out the form per say using their own device but on the clinic's wifi

Comment: your most ideal options would be, 1. login system, 2. temporary link sent to them via sms or email by clinic staff, 3. or password protected form where staff clinic give them temporary password to access the form

Comment: @silver, i love the idea of giving a temporary password that is sent to them which expires after they submit  or after a time period. Thank you :)

Comment: you can have a temporary password database where staff can create a password, then mark it when its being use and set it on user session/cookie, then once form submission comes connected to that session/cookie, delete it from the database.